# viewForZoomingInScrollView

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a few buttons that each load a different image a UIScrollView, you can zoom in on these images. What happens is that after selecting a new images the previous one is still there in the scrollview. How do I clean up the scroll view before opening a new image in there?

This is the code so far:

```
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView: (UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return imgView;
}
-(IBAction)buttonClicked: (UIButton *)sender{
    switch (sender.tag) {
        case 1:{
            UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Gath.jpg"]];
            self.imgView = myImageView;
            [myImageView release];

            scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
            scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
            scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
            scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            scrollView.delegate = self;
            [scrollView addSubview:imgView];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep adding new subviews without removing the previous ones. You could just replace the image content in the existing imageView instead of making a new one.

Replace this:

```
   UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Gath.jpg"]];
    self.imgView = myImageView;
    [myImageView release];
```

with

```
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gath.jpg"];
```

and remove this

```
    [scrollView addSubview:imgView];
```

I assume you have linked the imageView to self.imageView elsewhere, such as in the storyboard, or when you create the scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

[myImageView removeFromSuperView];

myImageView=nil;

myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Gath.jpg"]];